Unable to run the code for "n" number of users in Appium Automation
In the Code i have to run the onboarding screen only once, with n number of test data but here i am calling that signup method from the configuration screen in profile class where it will run for first time, but for the second time in app onboarding screen won't be displayed so that i need to avoid that signup method in code for the second time is there a way?
can you please help me out.
public class Profile extends Configuration {
@Test(dataProvider="getData")
public void account(String Aadharid, String username, String password) throws InterruptedException {

    singup(); 
    android.Signupscreen();
    android.Aadharscreen(Aadharid);
    android.Aadharidarrowbutton();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    android.Usernameset(username);
    android.Passwordset(password);
    android.loginbutton("9876543210", "Password@123", "Password@123");
    android.getText();
    android.clickMyButton();
    android.logout();
         
}

@BeforeMethod
public void preset() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    android.setActivity();
}

@DataProvider
public Object[][] getData() {
    return new Object[][] { 
        {"456789065478","raju","password@1"},
        {"678954326790","ajith","Password@123"}
    };
}

public void singup() throws InterruptedException {
    android.Onboardclick();
}

public void Onboardclick() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    Onboardingscreen.click();
}

}
